# Solution of underdetermined linear system with additional constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

If I know rectangular matrices $H,S$ of size $NxM$ where $M >> N$, also I know that $HS^T=I$ and $rank(H)=rank(S)=N$. Is there an efficient way to find matrix $X$ such that $XH=I$? Or at least solve equation $Hx=y$ for $x$, such that $HS^T=I$

Comment: S and H are full row rank

Comment: If $\rm H$ has full row rank, then the solution of $\rm X H = I$ is $$\rm X = H^\top ( H H^\top )^{-1}$$

Comment: But is there a way to somehow use information that $HS^T=I$? Not just solve $Hx=y$ in least square sense? Maybe this constraint is useless, though I'm not sure.

Comment: There always exists $S$ such that $HS^T = I$. On the other hand, the equation $XH = I$ does not have a solution. The problem is that you map a big space into a small one with $H$ so that you have a big loss. This loss can not be equalized by applying some $X$ from the left.

Comment: I see @amsmath, makes sense, need to look for constrains somewhere else. I'll reformulate this question with more domain information then.